# Bad data being received

Tags: python, list, split, server, client

I am writing a client and server app in Python and I have a problem with received data. In the first "loop" I received good data but in the next "loop" I received bad data. What do I have to do? Maybe you have a better idea to send and receive data.

This is Client:

```
import socket
import pickle
import sys

host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 2004
BUFFER_SIZE = 100000 
print("What you want to do:\r1. Select from base\r2.Insert into base")
MESSAGE, MESSAGE1 = input("tcpClientA: Enter message/ Enter   exit:").split(",")
tcpClientA = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
tcpClientA.connect((host, port))
while MESSAGE != 'exit':
    tcpClientA.send(MESSAGE.encode())
    tcpClientA.send(MESSAGE1.encode())
    lista=pickle.loads(tcpClientA.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).strip())
    print(lista)
    print("Variables 1 and 2 are: ", MESSAGE, MESSAGE1)
    MESSAGE, MESSAGE1 = input("tcpClientA: Enter message to continue/     Enter exit:").split(",")    

tcpClientA.close()
```

This is Server:

```
import socket 
from threading import Thread
import pyodbc
import pickle

# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Thread Pool
class ClientThread(Thread): 

    def __init__(self,ip,port): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.ip = ip 
        self.port = port 
        print ("[+] New server socket thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port) )

    def run(self): 
        while True :           
            connsql = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=I7-KOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=test')
            cursor = connsql.cursor()            
            data = conn.recv(2048)

            #datasplitx, datasplity = data.decode().split(",", 1)  
            try:
                xy = []
                xy = data.decode().split(" ")
                print("dat: ",data.decode())
                print("After del:",xy)
                x=str(xy[0])
                #y=str(xy[1])
                #x, y = [str(x) for x in data.decode().split()]  
                #y=str(datasplit[1])
                #x = str(datasplit[0])
                #y = str(datasplit[1])

            except ValueError:
                print("List does not contain value")
            print ("Server received data:", xy)
            if x == 'exit':
                break
            if x == '1':
            #if data.decode() == '1':
                cursor.execute("select rtrim(name) from client")
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
                zap=pickle.dumps(rows)
                conn.send(zap)
                print(pickle.loads(zap))

            if x == '2':    
            #if data.decode() == '2':             
                cursor.execute("insert into dbo.klient values('"+y+"')")
                connsql.commit()
                zro=pickle.dumps("Done.")
                conn.send(zro)
            del xy[:]
            print ("cleared list: xy",xy)

# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Program Stub
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0' 
TCP_PORT = 2004 
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024  # Usually 1024, but we need quick response 

tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)) 
threads = []

while True: 
    tcpServer.listen(4) 
    print ("Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...\r" )
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpServer.accept() 
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port) 
    newthread.start() 
    threads.append(newthread) 
    print("Client IP: " +str(ip))

for t in threads:
t.join()
```

Comment: What kind of *bad data* do you receive? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I want enter in input two variables and send them. Server will recieve data and now i want split to two variables and used to in select, insert etc.
In first time after run app I enter "1, data_string" server recieved two variables next time i enter the same variables and I recieved in list "1" nothing else. I don't know where is my second variables.

Comment: I have solution for my problem:  
tcpClientA.send(MESSAGE.encode())
tcpClientA.send(MESSAGE1.encode())
to
data= MESSAGE+MESSAGE1
tcpClientA.send(data.encode())